# TV shows database: delete shows that has foreign key seasons

Tags: php, mysql

I'm building a backpanel to my TV series website I have 2 tables. One called shows and the other called seasons.

Structure:
Shows - `show_id PK`, `show_title`

Seasons - `season_id PK`, `show_id` (Foreign key), `season`

I'm listing all the tv show names in a table in the backend with a delete button however when i press delete it will not delete the show because it has seasons attached too it. If i try delete a show that has no seasons attached it removes it from the database with no problem.

My code looks like this on remove.php:

```
$id=$_GET['id'];

// Delete show
$sql="DELETE FROM shows WHERE shows_id='$id'";

$result=mysql_query($sql);
```

I'm guessing i would also need to remove the seasons assigned too the same show but i'm unsure on how to go about doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using InnoDB for your MySQL table, life could be really simple for you here if you checked / changed the constraints on your Foreign Key.

Changing these depends on how you set it up, whether you're using command line interface or some GUI to manage your db.

But when you created the foreign key field in your seasons table, you set up constraints. If you update that constraint to be as follows:

**On Update: Do Nothing
\\ On Delete: Cascade**

Now any time you delete a row from shows, whatever associated season rows exist will be deleted automatically because of the cascade rule. Very helpful, and a must for setting up normalized databases.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html

Answer (score 1):

```
$id=$_GET['id'];

// Delete all seasons for this show first.
$sql="DELETE FROM seasons WHERE show_id='$id'";

// Now, Delete show
$sql="DELETE FROM shows WHERE id='$id'";
```